# Typescript Interface with nullable properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface *IFilterSet*  with nullable fields:

```
export interface IFilterSet {
        filter1?: boolean;
        filter2?: boolean;
        filter3?: number;
        fitler4?: string;
    }
```

I receive another *object X*, that **may** contain IFilterSet object among others.

I want to map the IFilterSet properties of object X. 
First quess would be to make a loop for those properties, but because they are nullable, it won't work, there will be nothing to loop through.
Initialiazing an empty IFilterSet would defeat the purpose of those properties being nullable, right?

Comment: Why would it defeat the purpose? In the end, `{}` is assignable to `IFilterSet`. You can check for the presence of a property by calling `hasOwnProperty(prop)`.

Comment: You can also define your interface as 

`export interface IFilterSet {
        filter1: boolean | null;
        filter2: boolean | null;
        filter3: number | null;
        fitler4: string | null;
`
if you want the fields always be there, but have null values, but I like the first version more.

Comment: How would object X contain that `IFilterSet`? Would it be `X.filterSet`, `X.etc[?]`, or other way?

Comment: it would be X.filter1, X.filter2, X.SomeOtherStuff, X could have 0-all of IFilterSet properties

Comment: There are solutions for the problem at hand, like the one pointed out by Wickoo, I wonder what is the elegant, general solution for populating an Interface with optional properties, if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully get your question, but how about this:

```
function map(filterSet: IFilterSet, obj: X) {
    (obj as any)['filter1'] = filterSet.filter1;
    (obj as any)['filter2'] = filterSet.filter2;
    (obj as any)['filter3'] = filterSet.filter3;
    (obj as any)['filter4'] = filterSet.filter4;
}
```

This way, the X instance will get all the properties of `filterSet` and gets `undefined` for the ones are not present, but all the fields will end up there.

Or this (if you try to construct a new `IFilterSet` instance):

```
function map(obj: X): IFilterSet {
    return {
        filter1: (obj as any)['filter1'],
        filter2: (obj as any)['filter2'],
        filter3: (obj as any)['filter3'],
        filter4: (obj as any)['filter4']
    }
}
```

Here you will get an instance of `IFilterSet`, with their fields either `undefined`or the value of the `filter1` through `filter4`.

Either way you HAVE TO hardcode the name of fields, I'm not sure if you can get it differently.

Answer (score 1):

Defining optional properties like `filter1?` does not means that the value will be defined or `null`. It means that the property may be defined (or not).

Let say you receive the following object:

```
{
   "name": "foo",
   "type": "bar"
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
const filterSet = objectX as IFilterSet;

if (filterSet.filter1 === true) {
    console.log('Do something when filter1 is defined and true');
}
else if (filterSet.filter1 === false) {
    console.log('Do something when filter1 is defined and false');
}
else {
    console.log('filter1 is not true nor false (may be null, undefined or something else)');
}

const value2 = filterSet.filter2 || false;
const value3 = filterSet.filter3 || 0;
console.log('value2 and value3 will always have a value');
```

You don't really need to use `null` for those cases.

If you really need to isolate the properties of IFilterSet in a different object. I would recommend using a function like this one:

```
const filterSetFrom = (source: any) => {
    const filterSet = {};
    ['filter1', 'filter2', 'filter3', 'filter4']
        .forEach((property) => filterSet[property] = source[property] || null);
    return filterSet;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To have properties of `IFilterSet` as as properties of `X`, all you need to do is declare that `X` extends `IFilterSet`, or use type assertions if you can't control `X`s declaration.

```
class X implements IFilterSet {
    ...
}
...
const x:X = ...
const filterSet = x as IFilterSet;
```

If you're making properties of `IFilterSet` optional to obey lose structure of `X`, you could have `IFilterSet` with required properties (without `?`) and have 
`X` implement `Partial<IFilterSet>`. `Partial<T>` gives you a type with all properties of `T`, but made optional.